# Выбор объекта на яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На яндекс картах, по клику на объект можно вызвать такой пин, могу ли я вызвать такое же состояние карты, подключеной на моем сайте, то есть чтобы по умолчанию был выбран объект и показывался вот такой пин? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

API не даёт всех тех же возможностей, что и публичная карта Яндекс. Возможность открыть детальный балун с инфой об объекте есть через [**findOrganization**](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization.html?lang=ru), но получить конкретный общий или тем более персонализованный логотип публичных методов Яндекс не даёт.

Можете попробовать составить свой набор иконок для основных типов (**categories** в **orgGeoObject**) объектов и создавать их исходя из типа организации.

P.s.:
Вид, подобный тому, что вы просите, можно получить в виджете Карт, код которого можно получить по кнопке **[Поделиться](https://yandex.ru/support/maps/concept/get-map-reference.html#concept3)**. Если высота виджета будет **400 или более точек**, выбранный объект будет с открытым балуном, если **399 или менее** – балун схлопнется и будет только пином. Посмотрите пример: https://jsbin.com/yuhodez/edit?html,output